# When should I use "cross" and "pass" on radio telephony?

Tags: phraseology

Talking about "vertical" plan (altitudes, flight level) and "horizontal" plan (positions, way points), according to the standard phraseology FAA/ICAO, is there any difference, in the usage of, between TO CROSS and TO PASS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When related to a significant point, there is no difference between pass and cross. For altitude/FL only pass is used.

The phraselogies used by ATC is described in ICAO [Doc 4444](http://flightservicebureau.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/ICAO-Doc4444-Pans-Atm-16thEdition-2016-OPSGROUP.pdf) (Air Traffic Management / PANS-ATM), chapter 12, phraseologies. The document explains the meaning for ATC, therefore to be understood and used by pilots.

> 12.3.1.2 LEVEL CHANGES, REPORTS AND RATES
>
> - EXPEDITE CLIMB (or DESCENT) [UNTIL **PASSING** (level)]
> - AFTER **PASSING** (significant point)
>
> 12.3.1.4 TRANSFER OF CONTROL AND / OR FREQUENCY CHANGE
>
> - AT (or OVER) (time or place) [or WHEN] [**PASSING**/LEAVING/REACHING (level)] CONTACT (unit call sign)
>     (frequency)
>
> 12.3.1.10 ADDITIONAL REPORTS
>
> - REPORT **PASSING** (significant point)
> - REPORT **PASSING** (three digits) RADIAL (name of VOR) VOR
>
> 12.3.2.3 MAINTENANCE OF SPECIFIED LEVELS
>
> - MAINTAIN (level) UNTIL **PASSING** (significant point)
> - MAINTAIN (level) UNTIL (minutes) AFTER **PASSING** (significant point)
>
> 12.3.2.4 SPECIFICATION OF CRUISING LEVELS
>
> - **CROSS** (significant point) AT ( or ABOVE, or BELOW)
> - **CROSS** (distance) MILES, (GNSS or DME) [(direction)] OF (name of DME station) OR (distance) [(direction)] OF (significant point) AT (or ABOVE or 
>     BELOW) (level)
>
> 12.3.2.8 SEPARATION INSTRUCTIONS
>
> - **CROSS** (significant point) AT (time) [OR LATER (or OR BEFORE)]
> - ADVISE IF ABLE TO **CROSS** (significant point) AT (time or level)
>
> 12.3.3.1 DEPARTURE INSTRUCTIONS
>
> - AFTER REACHING (or **PASSING**) (level or significant point) ( instructions)
>
> 12.3.4.12 TURN OR CLIMB INSTRUCTIONS AFTER TAKE-OFF
>
> - AFTER **PASSING** (level) (instructions)
>
> 12.4.2.3 PARALLEL APPROACHES
>
> - YOU HAVE **CROSSED** THE LOCALIZER (or GBAS/SBAS/MLS FINAL APPROACH COURSE)

If another wording is used in some country, the differences must be explained in the country AIP, at section GEN 1.7. For USA ([FAA AIP](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/AIP.pdf)), Doc 4444 differences are found at GEN 1.7-23. There are none related.